# How to set individual shadow catcher objects per render layer

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, render-layers

I am using blender version 2.79.

Is there a way to set an object to be a shadow catcher in cycles settings per render layer?

**Example for a scene setup:**

Render layer 1:

- qube = red material
- sphere = blue material

Render layer 2:

- qube = *shadow catcher*
- sphere = blue material

Render layer 3:

- qube = red material
- sphere = *shadow catcher*

Are the examples possible? If you have a material setup for a shadow catcher or a way to do it in postpro this would help too.

I know there will be a new render layer organisation in upcoming v2.8 but I need a workaround now...

Thank you for all tips.

Best wishes from germany

Chris

Answer (score 1):

This is my workaround about it:

I Used 3 frames and set the **Shadow Catcher** for every object in its frame.

Let the mouse pointer over the **Shadow Catcher** checkbox and press  <kbd>I</kbd> , this will make a keyframe to that single frame.

Move to the next frame, check the **Shadow Catcher** and with mouse pointer over the **Shadow Catcher** checkbox and press  <kbd>I</kbd>  again.

To the next frame, unckeck the **Shadow Catcher** and with mouse pointer over the **Shadow Catcher** checkbox and press  <kbd>I</kbd>  again.

Repest it to the other object. But using: frame 1 - unckeked, frame 2 - unchecked and frame 3 - checked.

Render the 3 frames an Animation.

See the image below:

[image]

Comment: Hi LeoNas. Thank you for the answer. This is a possible solution.